# how to resolve overload errors in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-scroll

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-scroll'
import "./Protocol.css"
import { ANALYTICS, TRADE, USERS, TRADERS, VOTES, ZEROES } from "../../Constants"
const Protocol = () => {
    return (
        <div className="Protocol_container">
            <div className="Protocol_heading">
                {ANALYTICS}
            </div>
            <div className="Protocol_content">
                <Link>
                    <p>{ZEROES}</p>{TRADE}
                </Link>
                <Link >
                    <p>{ZEROES}</p>{USERS}
                </Link>
                <Link >
                    <p>{ZEROES}</p>{TRADERS}
                </Link>
                <Link>
                    <p>{ZEROES}</p>{VOTES}
                </Link>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
export default Protocol
```

getting err as

No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: LinkProps | Readonly): Link', gave the following error.
Property 'to' is missing in type '{ children: (string | Element)[]; }' but required in type 'Readonly'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: LinkProps, context: any): Link', gave the following error.
Property 'to' is missing in type '{ children: (string | Element)[]; }' but required in type 'Readonly'.

[image]

Comment: just add property `to` to your `Link`

Comment: you need to add the `to` property in your `Link` component. for example: `<Link to: '/home'>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link need prop to="where to go", if you want to go nowhere just use to="#"